# Azure service tags REST API and subscription level rights

Tags: azure

**Goal**

I want to use the [service tags REST API endpoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/servicetags/list) to get all the AzureCloud datacenter public IP addresses.

I am aware that I could manually download the generated `json` file from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519).

My end goal is to use the endpoint to programmatically automate a task.

**Problem**

I can get a response with status code 200 of about 46k lines, but the AzureCloud tag is nowhere in the response body. It skips from AzureBotService to AzureCognitiveSearch. I believe AzureCloud should be between those two tags.

**Steps**

Firstly, I created an account using the AZ CLI tool with `az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp"`.

With a tenant ID, app ID/client ID, password/client secret, subscription ID. I can use `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{ tenant_id }}/oauth2/token` to get a bearer token.

Using the bearer token, I can query the service tags using `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{ subscription_id }}/providers/Microsoft.Network/locations/eastus/serviceTags?api-version=2020-05-01`.

**What I've done**

I came across a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/12689) that is somewhat related to my problem stating that by design, we cannot get all the datacenter public IPs if the user does not have subscription level rights.

I tried the following commands to try to give subscription scope rights to my app, but to no avail:

- `az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp2" --role reader --scopes "/subscriptions/{{ subscription_id }}"` to create a new account while specifying reader role and scope of the subscription. (I have retried the API with the new IDs as well).
- `az role assignment create --assignee "{{ app_id }}" --role "Reader" --scope "/subscriptions/{{ subscription_id }}"` to create a new role and specify scope.
- `az role assignment create --assignee "{{ app_id }}" --role "Owner" --subscription "{{ subscription_id }}"` to create a new role and specify subscription.

My app still has the scope set to "This resource".

I suspect there is something I am misunderstanding about Azure, given I am completely new to Azure (just created a free trial account yesterday).

All help will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To use servicetags api you have to register Microsoft.Netowork resource provider at azure subscription level.

[image: In you subscription blade]

[image: Register Microsoft.Network]

Instead you can use these api:

to get the ip address list of  a specified Azure Service in a specified Azure region:
[https://azinfo.azurewebsites.net/api/servicetags/{regionName}/{serviceName}](https://azinfo.azurewebsites.net/api/servicetags/%7BregionName%7D/%7BserviceName%7D)

to get valid region names
https://azinfo.azurewebsites.net/api/GetRegionNameList

to get valid service names
https://azinfo.azurewebsites.net/api/GetServiceNameList

to get the all the ip address list of all Azure Services in a specified Azure region
[https://azinfo.azurewebsites.net/api/region/{regionName}](https://azinfo.azurewebsites.net/api/region/%7BregionName%7D)

Comment: please add the example as part of the answer itself, rather than linking to a remote resource.